# Div flickers with changing z-index with hover CSS selector

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit stuck trying to figure why this won't work. I have two divs overlaid one another, one with a caption and one without. The one without has a higher z-index, but on hover, it is supposed to z-index:0 to reveal the lower layer. When I hover over top of the div, the "wcaption" div displays properly. When I hover the caption area of the div, it flickers back and forth between the "wcaption" div and the "wocaption" div many times per second. I have tried it on other browsers and I get the same result.

```
<style>
#ad_content .ad_wocaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index:100;
}
#ad_content .ad_wocaption:hover {
    z-index: 0;
}
#ad_content .ad_caption {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.75;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    height: 60px ;
}
#opacity_filter {
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.75;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.75;
    width: 134px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;    
}
#ad_content .ad_caption p {
    color: fff;
    margin: 5px 8px;
}
#ad_content .ad_caption span {
    color: #696767;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#ad_content .ad_expand {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
</style>
<div class="ad_wocaption">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="images/ad_frleft.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="ad_expand" src="images/expand.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="ad_wcaption">
   <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="images/ad_frleft.jpg" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img class="ad_expand" src="images/expand.png" /></a>
   <div id="opacity_filter"></div>
   <div class="ad_caption">
        <p>KIA Forte surprises and delights...</p>
        <span>-MotorTrend</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's doing what it is suppose to do.

You see when you hover the element it loses it z-index and the other one pop on top of it, so when that happens you lose the hover effect on the first one and the z-index return to default and the first one pop up once gain, but since you again are trying to hover it lose it's z-index once again and so on and so on, you get the point until you stop hovering.

Comment: I see. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: You can add the hover effect to the parent holder (in your case you should add a holder to them) of those 2 divs, an change the z-index then.

Comment: I guess I'll have to add some javascript in order to do that.

Comment: I wish I could give you more internet points for this. Thank you very much